# localhost not working on Big Sur (Apache & Homebrew)

Tags: macos, apache, server, localhost, macos-big-sur

I know there are dozens of questions about Apache not working, but nothing seems to solve it for me. I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1.

I installed Apache with `brew install httpd` and then `brew services start httpd`. Everything seems to be okay, but going to `http://localhost/` gives me "This site can't be reached" error. `http://127.0.0.1/` also gives that error. My `/etc/hosts` configuration seems to be fine.

I don't understand what's wrong. What can I do to find out the issue?

Answer (score 21):

I assume you have tried to follow https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions tutorial. If not no worries. I followed this tutorial and I got the same issue.

As per my understanding you have updated to BigSur from previous version and there you have used `sudo` to install apache and php etc. Now it will not work due to permission issues.

I am able to make it run with the following steps

1. Change `Listen 80` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`
2. use `sudo /usr/local/bin/httpd -k start` to start your httpd

Rest follow the tutorial to install multiple versions of PHP, enabling PHP in `httpd.conf` file and PHP version switcher. After switching the version you must stop and start the httpd via sudo command i mentioned above.

So looks like things are working with this. I hope if I'm able to set proper permissions then I no longer need the sudo. And if you are at the tutorial, please check the comments at the bottom

Take care

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this solved my problem (after a solid 48hrs of scouring the web). Thank you!

Comment: It works for 5 min. I upgrade from catalina to big sur,  after a restart, apache isn't working. This work around only works 5 min, then apache is dead again

Comment: NOT work, instead,  simplely use:  apachectl start, works for me

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thanks bro!!

Comment: This partially worked for me, later I got error while starting httpd which solved by following command: brew reinstall apr-util

ref. link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273353/symbol-not-found-error-on-starting-httpd-mac

Answer (score 2):

I find that

```
apachectl stop


apachectl start
```

is the more reliable way to ensure httpd is running successfully.   Also always

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Comment: `apachectl stop` gives me: `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service. Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service`

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue, I upgrade from catalina to big sur, apache is well for a month, then a restart, apache isn't working.

I follow above,

```
       Change Listen 80 to Listen 127.0.0.1:80 in /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

This only make things worse.

I reinstall apache use brew https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions

same problem, not works above.

Finally, I change back Listen 10,

and

```
    sudo apachectl -k restart
```

make it works again.

Brew services list is wrong, misleading, not trust.

if I run

```
      brew services list
```

I got :

```
     Name  Status  User   Plist
     httpd error   root   /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
     mysql started gemini /Users/gemini/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

You can see httpd is error, in fact, my apache runs well,
so the info here is all wrong.

```
 !!!!!! if apache is not working !!!!!!
 
              run following to fix:
        
                        sudo apachectl -k stop
                        sudo apachectl -k start

                               or 
                  
                        sudo apachectl -k restart
               
               
               
              Check log:        

                        tail -f /usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log

     
 !!!!!! if apache is not working !!!!!!

            
            
            
            
            
            
            
 
            change default port to 10:
            
                        
                 edit file: 
                 
                         /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
                         
                         change to  Listen : 10
                         
                         

                 server root directory: 
 
                                     DocumentRoot "/usr/local/var/www"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Robo Robok

apachectl stop gives me: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service. Unload failed: 113: Could not find specified service

Solution:

1. sudo apachectl start
   first start the server
2. sudo apachectl stop
   then you can stop it

Answer (score 0):

```
$ brew update
$ brew install apache2
$ sudo apachectl start
```

Access the index page at http://localhost:80 or by simply visiting localhost on the browser.