# "Symbol not Found" Error on starting httpd (mac)

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

I am using Homebrew installed apache.

After installing and linking this, I am getting getting this error message when trying to run `apachectl start`:

```
Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.51/bin/httpd
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
/usr/local/bin/apachectl: line 79:  4894 Abort trap: 6
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing several times with Homebrew. This did not help.

What has gone wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the answer (https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2482)

```
brew reinstall apr-util
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer. Thank you for answering your own question. 

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the ```dyld[88779]: Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor```

Comment: Thanks, aslo fixes: dyld[9546]: Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_file_set_buf_size

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well after installing the Monterey 12.2.1 update that break it. (thanks Apple for making me loose 1h of my time after each upgrade :D)